# Can't get SWF file to run. Get's stuck at please "Right click click to run adobe flash player"

Tags: flash, nwjs

I'm writing an application with NWJS and I'm trying to get pepperflash to work with it. When I try to open an swf file, I get a message that I can't address that says "Right click to run adobe flash player"

I think I have installed pepperflash correctly as this dialog is showing up, but I can't seem to get the swf to run. I have tried adding this block         of code to my javascript:

```
 chrome.contentSettings.plugins.set({
 primaryPattern: "<all_urls>",
 resourceIdentifier: { id: "adobe-flash-player" },
 setting: "allow"
 });
```

Here's my js code:

```
    var win = nw.Window.get();
    win.width = 1000;
    win.height = 800;


    chrome.contentSettings.plugins.set({
    primaryPattern: "<all_urls>",
    resourceIdentifier: { id: "adobe-flash-player" },
    setting: "allow"
    });


    nw.Window.open('fishy.swf', {}, function(new_win) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I was missing a file or two from the flash plugin. Everything works now.